# jQuery – Add ID name of element to body class

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to add the class `.in-view` to whichever `div` is currently showing in the viewport (via this [jQuery-viewport-checker](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker) script).

I want to take the ID name of whichever div currently has the class `in-view` and add it to the `body` as a class name.

Here's what I've got so far. I've got as far as adding the active ID to a variable, and seeing if I can output this to the console, but no luck so far! The console just outputs 'undefined'.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mydiv').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'in-view' // This adds the class to any div that is in the viewport
    });
    var activeId = jQuery('.in-view').attr('id');
    window.console&&console.log(activeId, "Active div ID"); // Testing to see if variable contains the ID

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code showing the in-view div is running **immediately** after you call `viewportChecker`. Apparently, no `.mydiv` is in view at that time (or the plugin hasn't had a chance to mark it as in view yet).

I haven't used the plugin, but looking at [the docs](https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker), you'll want to use the `callbackFunction` option:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.mydiv').viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'in-view', // This adds the class to any div that is in the viewport
        callbackFunction: function(elem, action) {
            $(document.body).toggleClass(elem.attr("id"), action === "add");
        }
    });
});
```

The callback is called with `action` being `"add"` or `"remove"`, so I use `action === "add"` to decide whether to add the class or remove it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I needed to use `elem.attr("id")` so it must be a jQuery instance.

Comment: @jasonbradberry: Ah, thanks for letting me know. I updated the answer to use it. Glad that helped!